# Integrating the step size function under a Gaussian

Tags: calculus, probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am interesting in the following integral:

$\int \Theta(f_i -f_c)\mathcal{N}(f_c|m_c,\sigma^2_c)df_c$

where $\Theta()$ represent the heavised function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function. I have seen in many works that the result of this integral is given by:

$\phi(\frac{f_i-m_c}{\sigma_c})$

where $\phi()$ is the cumulative density function of a Gaussian.

What I have seen so far is that smooth approximations to the step-side function can be shown to be CDF functions in the limit. For instance:

$\theta(x)=\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{1}{2}[1+\text{erf}[kx]]=\phi(x)$

where $\text{erf}$ is the error function.

However I am not able to use this to solve the above integral. Can someone help me?.  One more point, is this result also valid for a multivariate Gaussian?

Thank you.

Comment: I feel like if you just write it out only using e.g. $\exp$ and not using this fancy notation $\mathcal N$ or $\Theta$ it will just come out automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Calvin Khor suggested, your integral is just a fancy way to write this:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{f_i}\mathcal{N}_{m_c,\sigma_c^2}(f_c)df_c=\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{f_i-m_c}{\sigma_c}}\mathcal{N}_{0,1}(u)du=\phi\left(\frac{f_i-m_c}{\sigma_c}\right)
$$

If the first transition is still problematic, write the $\mathcal{N}_{m_c,\sigma_c^2}(f_c)$ as $\frac{1}{\sigma_c\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(f_c-m_c)^2}{\sigma_c^2}\right)$ and substitute $u=(f_c-m_c)/\sigma_c$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. What I do not really get is how your answer can be expressed through this fancy notation, as Calvin Khor suggests. I mean, how the product of the Heaviside step function by a Gaussian is equal to integrating from $-\infty$ to $f_i$. Could you provide this step?. For values of $f_i\leq f_c$ this integral is 0, right?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okei, I want to add where my confusion came from, which is posted as an answer to Vasily.

I was considering that the value that changes is $f_i$, but it is $f_c$. We should consider that for values of $f_c$ above $f_i$ the integral is evaluated to 0, thus the part we are integrating from the Gaussian, is the left part, starting from $-\infty$ until $f_i$, which is the starting value from where the integral evaluates to 0.